# I can't launch my API through the docker image

Tags: java, docker, api

I downloaded a docker image of an API made in java that I hosted on the docker hub:

`docker pull claubermartins/back-crud-spring:2.0`

When I created the container and I try to run the API, I got the following warning after the code:

`docker run claubermartins/back-crud-spring: 2.0`

"Error: Unable to access jarfile backCrudSpring.jar"

The Dockerfile used to build the image:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} backCrudSpring.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","backCrudSpring.jar"]
```

Comment: I was looking at your image on Docker Hub and it looks like you have copied the jar file to `back-crud-spring.jar` rather than `backCrudSpring.jar`. Have you changed the Dockerfile and forgotten to push to docker hub?

Comment: I added the <finalName>backCrudSpring</finalName> argument
in pom.xml

Comment: @HansKilian is 100% right. The image pushed to hub does not contain `backCrudSpring`, but `back-crud-spring.jar`. See for yourself: override broken `entrypoint.sh` with `ls` like this:   `docker run --entrypoint ls --rm claubermartins/back-crud-spring:2.0 `

Comment: @JockX I uploaded the image incorrectly to Docker Hub, after typing the command `docker run --entrypoint ls --rm claubermartins/back-crud-spring:2.0` the file `back-crud-spring.jar` appears . So you and @HansKilian are 100% correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestions I typed the code `docker run --entrypoint ls --rm claubermartins/back-crud-spring:2.0` and verified that the name of the .jar file was wrong.

To confirm I generated a new image and uploaded it to the docker hub `docker build -t claubermartins/back-crud-spring:3.0 .` and it works perfectly with the command `docker run claubermartins/back-crud-spring:3.0`.

Concluding as soon as I uploaded the image with a different Dockerfile to the Hub.